# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, html

a.config.js

```
var a = 3;
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="a.config.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>  
 </body>
</html>
```

If I put this in my web root, chrome gives me the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (a.config.js:1)
```

Firefox gives me the error

```
syntax error (a.config.js:1)
```

If I run it from my filesystem instead of localhost, I get no errors.  If I rename a.config.js to a.confi.js (and modify the javascript include to match, I get no error.  I don't understand this at all.

Comment: What about in other browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What does the browser see when it requests *a.config.js*? Maybe there is some URL rewriting involved.

Comment: This question helped me find the answer.  The server was returning a 200 status code, but returned the response, "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."  I played around with apache's http.conf file.  Commenting out the include of mod_aspdotnet.conf made the file return correctly.  Perhaps config.js has a special meaning in the .net world?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting a 404. Make sure you put the `a.config.js` file in the right place (in the same directory as the html file).